# Add a javascript to any cms page magento

Tags: cms, javascript

I would really like to use this on a single cms page in magento. For some reason it will not show the content.

[page with script](http://smartphone-kopen.nl/daisycon)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
mediaid=191156;subid='';entry=25;provider='0';duration=0;renewal=0;daisyconTelecomFilterView=1;col='1111111';programs='all';header='FFFFFF';background_price='E2F0FB';border='ECECEC';button_text='Bekijken';button_color='FF8300';button_hover='FF9E3D';button_textcolor='FFFFFF';font='Arial';slider='3694C7';minMob='0';maxMob='1000';minMin='100';maxMin='3000';minInt='200';maxInt='6000';minAb='0';maxAb='100';mobiles='all';
// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/mobielvergelijker/general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/mobielvergelijker/jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you want to add js file in every cms page?

Comment: No on just one page i need above script,  tried allready to fix trough xml layout update -->> No go

Answer (score 11):

Magento has a `core/text` type block that accepts text input from the layout XML. If you want to add the same files to all the CMS pages add the following to, for example, your `local.xml`

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="core/text"><action method="setText">
           <param>
<![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">mediaid=191156;subid='';entry=25;provider='0';duration=0;renewal=0;daisyconTelecomFilterView=1;col='1111111';programs='all';header='FFFFFF';background_price='E2F0FB';border='ECECEC';button_text='Bekijken';button_color='FF8300';button_hover='FF9E3D';button_textcolor='FFFFFF';font='Arial';slider='3694C7';minMob='0';maxMob='1000';minMin='100';maxMin='3000';minInt='200';maxInt='6000';minAb='0';maxAb='100';mobiles='all';</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/mobielvergelijker/general.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/mobielvergelijker/jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script>
          ]]>
                </param>
             </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

### Edit :

If you add these code in particular cms page. Then goto `cms > pages` then click on your page in `design tab` you can add the above code with out `<cms_page>` tag in `Layout Update XML`

Comment: that does not work either. :(

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Are you getting any errors or issues? and did @Meenakshi's method work?

Comment: cache is disabled,  @Meenakshi's method did not work either.   there are no errors just a blank page.

Comment: can you set ini_set('display_errors', 1); in your index page?

Comment: In the above example there is a `<!CDATA[...]]>` tag within a `<!CDATA[...]]>` tag which is not possible (without any tricks). So probably that's what causing it to fail?
You should remove the CDATA inside your Javascript tags. Also, this is not necessary/outdated, but that's a whole different discussion [out there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag)...

Comment: @7ochem thanks for that. Was being a bit sloppy there. Changed it!

Answer (score 8):

Finally got it working. All the javascript files local on server now.

Code below I put in layout update xml field.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <script>jquery-1.8.3.min.js</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <script>general.js</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <script>jquery.nouislider.min.js</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <script>example.min.css</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <script>example.min.css</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <script>nouislider.fox.css</script>
    </action>
</reference>
```

The code I use for the content of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
mediaid=171164;subid='smako';entry=25;provider='0';duration=0;renewal=0;daisyconTelecomFilterView=1;col='1111111';programs='all';header='FFFFFF';background_price='E2F0FB';border='ECECEC';button_text='Bekijken';button_color='FF8300';button_hover='FF9E3D';button_textcolor='FFFFFF';font='Arial';slider='3694C7';minMob='0';maxMob='1000';minMin='100';maxMin='3000';minInt='200';maxInt='6000';minAb='0';maxAb='100';mobiles='all';
// ]]></script>
<div id="mobile-comparator-wrapper" class="mobile-comparator-wrapper" style="background-color: #ffffff !important;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In admin *CMS -> Pages -> Design -> XML Layout Update*

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <script>js/filename.js</script>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Source: (Has an error in the script path, which I fixed here.)
http://www.mindfreakerstuff.com/2012/10/add-javascript-css-to-home-page-or-specific-cms-page-magento/

Another option is to inline code as such. Note you'll need a name for the block.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="anal-expe.js" >
        <action method="setText">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("you rock!");
                    </script>
                ]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```